# sudo apt update creates issues

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, bluetooth

````
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:6 https://deb.librewolf.net focal InRelease                                
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu focal InRelease              
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Hit:18 https://ubuntugis.qgis.org/ubuntugis focal InRelease                    
Err:13 https://debian.qgis.org/debian lsb_release InRelease                    
  Could not connect to debian.qgis.org:443 (2606:4700:3035::6815:4729). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to debian.qgis.org:443 (2606:4700:3035::ac43:8f17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to debian.qgis.org:443 (172.67.143.23), connection timed out Could not connect to debian.qgis.org:443 (104.21.71.41), connection timed out
Err:15 https://debian.qgis.org/debian focal InRelease         
  Unable to connect to debian.qgis.org:https:
Err:16 https://debian.qgis.org/debian artful InRelease
  Unable to connect to debian.qgis.org:https:
Err:17 https://debian.qgis.org/debian bionic InRelease
  Unable to connect to debian.qgis.org:https:
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://qgis.org/ubuntugis focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386```
````

Comment: You have two problems.  First, the bluez repository doesn't support Focal.  Secondly, `debian.qgis.org` doesn't resolve anywhere anymore.  So I would assume *both* the mentioned repositories are dead.

Comment: Just cutting and pasting an error message her is not how this forum works.